# Best way to optimize DB inserts using Java

Tags: java, oracle, optimization, concurrency, publish-subscribe

The program is written in java. 25 threads are processing 1 million tasks. Each task saves data into DB hence 1 million times DB insert happens. In order to optimize this, We tried following approach

1. Tasks save data into ConcurrentLinkedDeque
2. A thread polls the duque in periodic interval and gets all the available objects at that point in time.
3. Once the available objects' count reaches a threshold ( say 100K ), then create a thread to save.

But this approach is not improving overall performance.

I would like to reduce the number of times (1 million times currently ) DB insert happens to improve performance. Are there any alternate solution like High Performing -  multiple concurrent publisher and single concurrent subscriber kind of implementation ?

Comment: 1. You should use https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing. Make some experiments to choose the best batch size 2. Performance of inserts/updates strongly depend on DB things like table size, data types used, indexes, constraints like foreign keys, triggers etcetc. You may need to optimize your DB/tables for insert. A classical trick is to drop indexes before massive load and restore them after all the data loaded. Normally, you may expect up to 5k of inserts per sec for one single thread (for one single HDD). 3. Experiment how many threads give you the most performant loading 1-10..-50?

Comment: Also, you should check your algo. "pool...in periodic interval" sounds like you may introduce additional latency/a throughput limitation... What if you do "poll" with a small timeout to fill-in new batch? BTW, why do you need another thread to save, why wouldn't save in the pooling thread? Anyway, you should start with knowing your limitations - how many inserts you can achieve in one single thread (with a test loop) for your particular DB/table. Choose the right batch size. Then run more threads and see the difference...

Comment: @AnatolyG, thanks for your comments. Table is partitioned and has 100+ million records per partition. Hence dropping index while insert and adding index back will not work. Polling thread is not saving as i would like improve performance. When polling and accumulating records, if reaches a threshold ( say 30k records ), i spawn a thread to save. this approach is also not yielding good performance.

Comment: Have you tried to insert the data into a temp table without any indexes and any restrictions, and then execute INSERT with SELECT into the target table with parallelization enabled for both INSERT and SELECT to have all this hard work done on the server's side? BTW, again, "Polling thread is not saving as I would like to improve performance. "... I'm sure this split into 2 sequential steps doesn't improve performance but makes it a bit worse. Pool and build a PreparedStatement with the batch in one thread. Try 2...N such threads to be running simultaneously...

Comment: You also may try simultaneous loading into each partition. Let's assume, you have N partitions and there are N threads that pool and execute batches. Each thread makes inserts into its own, specific partition.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the overhead of row-by-row processing by batching commands. Many APIs include ways to batch commands, or you can combine them yourself with a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_no, name, price)
SELECT 1, 'Cheese', 9.99 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Bread' , 1.99 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Milk'  , 2.99 FROM dual;
```

Comment: yes, I am doing it in batch statements using PreparedStatement - addBatch and executeBatch.

Comment: There is a point where you can't go further, You have millions of data, so you may require millions of queries. You can optimize, but there is always a top.